# Change FontFamily for all elements

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there an easy and quick way to change the FontFamily for **all** elements (Textblocks, Textboxes etc.) in my application?

I use ModernUI which defines a lot of nice styles. I'd preferably not change any of these by hand. Setting the FontFamily application wide like this

```
public MainWindow()
{
    ...
    this.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS");
}
```

has no effect. I have also tried this in my App.xaml

```
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
        </Style>
```

and it changed the font for some elements, but not for all. If, e.g., a style such as `{StaticResource Small}` is set on an element, then changing the font through the App.xaml had no effect.

Comment: have you tried setting font family on the window?

Comment: Yes, I have. It had no effect, unfortunatly.

Comment: IMO, it wouldn't make sense if you override style on control level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because FontFamily is different property for TextBlock and Other control:

```
TextBlock : FrameworkElement
Control : FrameworkElement
```

And each of them have own FontFamily property, So you must set style for `TextBlock` and another style for `Control`.

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
     <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
 </Style>

 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
     <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
 </Style>
```

Comment: Reza, this works only for some elements. If, e.g., a TextBlock uses another Style from ModernUI such as <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" .. /> So I guess I have to adjust all used styles

Comment: @peter, You must override ModernUI styles with own custom style with  BasedOn="{StaticResource Heading2}" and use your custom style for TextBlocks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to search for "DefaultFontFamily", since that points to the font used in the [themes of ModernUI](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/blob/master/1.0/FirstFloor.ModernUI/FirstFloor.ModernUI/Themes/ModernDialog.xaml).

Comment: but if he overrides it on the control he won't get new style applied because this style will override his global style.

Comment: Would overwriting the DefaultFontFamily work? (i tried but it didn't but that doesn't mean it does not work ;o)  ´<FontFamily x:Key="DefaultFontFamily">Comic Sans MS</FontFamily>-->´

Comment: @peter I suppose so. I'm not familiar with ModernUI, but in general it is good practice to centralize these things and use themes etc, so you'd only need to change these things in one place.